# Python: split string with delimiters from a list

Tags: python, regex, string, split

**I'd like to split a string with delimiters which are in a list.**

The string has this pattern: **Firstname, Lastname Email**

The list of delimiters has this: **[', ',' ']** taken out of the pattern.

I'd like to split the string to get a list like this
**['Firstname', 'Lastname', 'Email']**

For a better understanding of my problem, this is what I'm trying to achieve:

The user shall be able to provide a source pattern: `%Fn%, %Ln% %Mail%` of data to be imported
and a target pattern how the data shall be displayed:

```
%Ln%%Fn%; %Ln%, %Fn; %Mail%
```

**This is my attempt:**

```
data = "Firstname, Lastname Email"

for delimiter in source_pattern_delimiter:
    prog = re.compile(delimiter)
    data_tuple = prog.split(data)
```

How do I 'merge' the data_tuple list(s)?

Comment: A more robust approach would be to build a regex from the source pattern itself, but I guess you don't need to be that precise for this application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import re

re.split(re.compile("|".join([", ", " "])), "Firstname, Lastname Email")
```

hope it helps

Comment: Great! This works quite well. I will consider user87690's suggestion as well, as there could be a Firstname like 
First name for the real data with e.g. two first names.

Comment: just an additional one. How do I get the split elements in uppercase? Thanks, Murat

Comment: can you please provide input example.

Comment: This "Firstname, Lastname Email" becomes['Firstname', 'Lastname', Email'] with above expression. I need ['FIRSTNAME', 'LASTNAME', EMAIL'].

Comment: please see is this what you need `re.split(r"\s(?=[A-Z])", "First name, Lastname Email")` output is `['First name,', 'Lastname', 'Email']`.

Comment: sry, now i see edit. i had something totally different on mind. try this `[ x.upper() for x in re.split(re.compile("|".join([", ", " "])), "Firstname, Lastname Email") ]`

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I needed. I'm still not used to use such expressions :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems you want something like this,

```
>> s = "Firstname, Lastname Email"
>>> delim = [', ',' ']
>>> re.split(r'(?:' + '|'.join(delim) + r')', s)
['Firstname', 'Lastname', 'Email']
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution without regexes and if you want to apply a particular delimiter at a particular position:

```
def split(s, delimiters):
    for d in delimiters:
        item, s = s.split(d, 1)
        yield item
    else:
        yield s

>>> list(split("Firstname, Lastname Email", [", ", " "]))
["Firstname", "Lastname", "Email"]
```

Comment: In my opinon, this is the most correct solution. The regular expression does not handle cases such as `'first name, lastname email'`. BTW, the `else` clause for the `for` loop is not needed. Just unindent the `yield s` statement.

Comment: @HaiVu: Thank you for your appreciation. I know the `else` clause is not needed, I just thought it suits this use case.

Comment: @user87690: Thank you for your contribution. Do you have any ideas to handle data where the firstname has 2 elements (so 2 firstnames).
Basically saying: How to handle data which is not matching the source pattern.


Example data: Murat Ugur, Lastname muratg@mail; John, Doe John@mail


With your method I get:
FN: Ugur, LN: Lastname, Mail: Muratmuratg@mail

Comment: @MuratG: 
>>> list(split("Murat Ugur, Lastname muratg@mail.mail", [", ", " "]))
['Murat Ugur', 'Lastname', 'muratg@mail.mail']

Answer (score 0):

What about splitting on spaces, then removing any trailing commas?

```
>>> data = "Firstname, Lastname Email"
>>> [s.rstrip(',') for s in data.split(' ')]
['Firstname', 'Lastname', 'Email']
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for a template based way to reconstruct the split data. The following script could give you an idea how to progress. It first splits the `data` into the three parts and assigns each to a dictionary entry. This can then be used to give a target pattern:

```
import re

data = "Firstname, Lastname Email"

# Find a list of entries and display them
entries = re.findall("(\w+)", data)
print entries       

# Convert the entries into a dictionary
dEntries = {"Fn": entries[0], "Ln": entries[1], "Mail": entries[2]}

# Use dictionary-based string formatting to provide a template system
print "%(Ln)s%(Fn)s; %(Ln)s, %(Fn)s; %(Mail)s" % dEntries
```

This displays the following:

```
['Firstname', 'Lastname', 'Email']
LastnameFirstname; Lastname, Firstname; Email
```

If you really need to use the exact template system you have provided then the following could be done to first convert your target pattern into one suitable for use with Python's dictionary system:

```
def display_with_template(data, target_pattern):
    entries = re.findall("(\w+)", data)
    dEntries = {"Fn": entries[0], "Ln": entries[1], "Mail": entries[2]}

    for item in ["Fn", "Ln", "Mail"]:
        target_pattern= target_pattern.replace("%%%s%%" % item, "%%(%s)s" % item)

    return target_pattern % dEntries

print display_with_template("Firstname, Lastname Email", r"%Ln%%Fn%; %Ln%, %Fn%; %Mail%")
```

Which would display the same result, but uses a custom target pattern:

```
LastnameFirstname; Lastname, Firstname; Email
```

Comment: yes. I have to put this into a dict to then use the source pattern to create a target pattern.
I use this expression:
`filtered_text_data_in_source_pattern[key] = dict(zip(source_pattern_elements, text_data_element_tuple))`

Comment: I tried to use your ideas, but struggle a bit.

**What I'm trying to do is following:**

I have my source pattern **["LN", "FN", "MAIL"]**

I have my source patttern delimiters **[", ", " "]**

I have my data put into a dict which looks like this:
**{1: ['LN': 'G', 'FN': 'Murat', 'MAIL': 'muratg@mail.com']}**
I have my target pattern **["Ln", "Fn", "Ln", "Fn", "Mail"]** --> This is for flexibility

if the user does not want to use all elements.
I have my target pattern delimiters **['', '; ', ', ', '; ']**

How do I put the data now into the target pattern together with the delimiters?